# Angular set properties on click event

Tags: angular

When a button is clicked the updateLocation method is called but I'm getting an "coordinates" is null error.

Any ideas?

```
export class SharedLocationComponent {
  @Input() coordinates: CoordinateModel;

  updateLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setCoordinates, function () {
        return true;
      });
    }
  }

  setCoordinates(coordinates) {
    let c = coordinates.coords
    if (c) {
      this.coordinates = new CoordinateModel(c.latitude, c.longitude);
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Can you show the HTML where your component "SharedLocationComponent" is called ?

Comment: Try: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setCoordinates.bind(this), ...` or define the callback as an arrow function: `setCoordinates = (coordinates) => { ... }`.

Comment: ^^^ fat arrow or that = this trick should sort ya.